# Nested json to data frame python (instagram json)

Tags: json, pandas, nested

So I downloaded my messaging json from IG and trying to turn it into a DataFrame. All I'm interested is the message content of one sender ('sabinabacevich') to another ('panbacevich'). Here is how the json looks:

```
 [{'participants': ['panbacevich', 'sabinabacevich'], 
   'conversation':
                  [{'sender': 'panbacevich', 'created_at': '2018-09- 
                  11T07:43:00.344130+00:00', 'media_owner': 'tyrone', 
                  'media_share_caption': 'Fr lol', 'media_share_url': 
                  'https://scontent-lax3- 1.cdninstagram.com/vp/
                  18f52cd945b10a7c6612ccb1644ee0a3/5C320320/t51.2885- 
                  15/e35/40456720_1886441298071798_219870885965499684_n.jpg? 
                  ig_cache_key=MTg2NTYxNjkxOTEyNzQ2NzY5Mg%3D%3D.2'}, 
                  {'sender':
```

I went through most of the nested examples I founf online, but can't get there. Pls send help

Answer (score 1):

First of all the json you have posted above is not valid json, I ran it through an online validator (this one: https://jsonlint.com/) and cleaned it up a bit so it looks like this:

```
[{"participants": ["panbacevich", "sabinabacevich"],
     "conversation": [{"sender": "panbacevich",
                       "created_at": "2018-09-11T07:43:00.344130+00:00",
                       "media_owner": "tyrone",
                       "media_share_caption": "Fr lol",
                       "media_share_url": "https://scontent-lax3-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/%2018f52cd945b10a7c6612ccb1644ee0a3/5C320320/t51.2885-%2015/e35/40456720_1886441298071798_219870885965499684_n.jpg?%20ig_cache_key=MTg2NTYxNjkxOTEyNzQ2NzY5Mg%3D%3D.2"
                       }]
     }]
```

Note that I have removed the field 'sender'.

From there it's relatively simple to load it into a dataframe using the json package:

```
import json

import pandas as pd

file = [{"participants": ["panbacevich", "sabinabacevich"],
     "conversation": [{"sender": "panbacevich",
                       "created_at": "2018-09-11T07:43:00.344130+00:00",
                       "media_owner": "tyrone",
                       "media_share_caption": "Fr lol",
                       "media_share_url": "https://scontent-lax3-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/%2018f52cd945b10a7c6612ccb1644ee0a3/5C320320/t51.2885-%2015/e35/40456720_1886441298071798_219870885965499684_n.jpg?%20ig_cache_key=MTg2NTYxNjkxOTEyNzQ2NzY5Mg%3D%3D.2"
                       }]
     }]

data = json.dumps(file)

df = pd.read_json(data)
```

From there the column 'conversation' can be accessed by `df.conversation.values` and then the dict that you want is inside a list inside a list. It can be broken out by:

```
dict_you_want = df.conversation.values[0][0]
```

From there you can access anything you want as you would from a regular dictionary:

```
print(dict_you_want['media_share_caption'])
"Fr lol"
```

Note that if the Dataframe was longer than 1 row, you would also have to select which row you want to access.

Hope that helps!